# Will it work : Deactivate Viber to delete message?

Tags: instant-messaging, viber

Suppose someone has Viber and sent a sensitive photo message (say a user-password) to a wrong person that never should see that.

The message was sent(any status on the bottom of the screen, but it was sent), but the receiver isn't online (yet).

After the sender understood its fault, there is a way to prevent the reciever to see the message hen it comes online by deactivating the viber account?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work.

As tested, deactivating viber account will remove local (and perhaps server) history, but once the infromation (text or picture) is sent, it will arrive anyway to the reciever when it comes online.